# Any drawbacks to using functions instead of classes for plain JavaScript components?

Tags: javascript, performance

Does using functions instead of classes in order to build plain JavaScript components have a major impact on performance or any other negative consequences? I prefer functions as I don't have to keep track of `this` and find the code much easier to read. One example component built using functions would be the following:

```js
function Dialog(dialog) {
  const dialogId = dialog.id;
  const trigger = document.querySelector(`[${DATA_TARGET}="${dialogId}"]`);
  const backdrop = dialog.closest(SELECTOR_BACKDROP);

  function show() {
    ...
  }

  function hide() {
    ...
  }

  trigger.addEventListener("click", show);
}

const dialogs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR_DIALOG));

dialogs.forEach((dialog) => Dialog(dialog));
```

Comment: The main disadvantage you loose the benefits of the prototype.   IOW:  every instance of  Dialog you create your going to have another copy of `show()`, `hide()`.. Etc,  using a class uses the protototype chain, so you only have 1 copy of `show` / `hide`..  But in practise it doesn't make much of a difference, unless your creating 1000's of them.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware that there would be a performance hit because memory is allocated for each function but my guess is that it is unnoticeable in real world use. Also although I'm not familiar with React, I saw React hooks, which are simple functions, are now considered best practice so it looks like this approach is okay.